# Strange behavior on SSH public key login

Tags: ssh, permissions, public-key, authorized-keys

I'm really stuck here. I've been trying to ssh into my ec2 server from local with a public key but it is not working. -> I get permission Denied (public key).

The set up is as follows: 
Local: generated public key pair and copied contents of id_rsa.pub.
Remote: ssh-ed into my EC2 server with the PEM file and pasted id_rsa.pub contents into new line of authorized keys file in .ssh folder.

Should work right? I noticed a common mistake is permissions, but mine seem to be set correctly:

**Remote Permissions:**

```
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Jul 23 04:00 .ssh
```

and in .ssh:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  404 Jul 24 03:19 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1679 Jul 24 03:19 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user  529 Jul 26 20:53 authorized_keys
```

**Local:**

```
drwx------    10 robvanhaaren  staff    340 Jul 26 18:43 .ssh
```

and in .ssh:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 robvanhaaren  staff   404 Jul 26 21:28 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 robvanhaaren  staff  1766 Jul 26 21:28 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 robvanhaaren  staff  5987 Jul 26 21:29 known_hosts
```

But when I run:

```
Robs-MacBook-Air-2:.ssh robvanhaaren$ ssh ec2-54-85-62-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com -l ec2-user -v
```

it returns:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-85-62-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.85.62.99] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 7a:d3:6c:7f:64:5d:b1:7b:2e:bb:73:0c:ce:0c:17:77
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-85-62-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/robvanhaaren/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The strange thing is that I CAN log in with public key to the server from my other ec2 server. **So the problem seems to be on my local machine**, not the remote.

Please help!

Comment: Have you checked `/var/log/auth.log`? Are there any relevant logs?

Comment: Are you using the same set of keys to log in from your other ec2 server?

Comment: maybe you didn't add to authorized_keys properly. ssh-copy-id can do it automatically. First enable user/pass login i.e. `PasswordAuthentication yes` in sshd_config, and you can then use `ssh-copy-id user@host` then it will automatically add to authorized_keys, and next time it will use the key, and you can turn off user/pass login if you want

Answer (score 2):

SSH issues can be a hassle. I always start with the following. I have the commands saved in a cheat sheet so I never have to fear typo's.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* \
&& chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys \
&& chown -r <username>:<username> /home/<username>/.ssh \
&& chown -r <username>:<username> /home/<username>/.ssh/*
```

If that doesn't work, I'd remove authorized_keys and re create it (mind the ownership & permissions), making sure to copy the contents from notepad, or another proper text editor. Wordpad and other fat editors can mess keys up. You can also remove the remote host's entry from the known_hosts file. I remember having to do that once for something.

Comment: you write "If that doesn't work, I'd remove authorized_" <-- you mean authorized_keys

Comment: Yes, authorized_keys ^_^ (editing)

Comment: It looks like the authorized_keys and id_rsa.pub files are different sizes - I would think that is the issue here.

Comment: @JacobHume you should elaborate on that statement, since authorized_keys may have that id_rsa.pub and more

Comment: You write "You can also remove the remote host's entry from the known_hosts file" <-- or remote the known_hosts file. Though the known_hosts issue is not the issue in his question.. The known_hosts issue is a dfiferent error something about a key changing..

Comment: @barlop The information in your id_rsa.pub file gets added to authorized_keys on the remote computer, setting up the trust for that key pair. Since the file sizes are different, it's possible that the public key info (id_rsa.pub) was not copied over correctly.

Comment: @JacobHume i'm aware that id_rsa.pub gets added to authorized_keys.. what I said to you was  authorized_keys may have that id_rsa.pub **and more**  i.e. if it had more then the file sizes wouldn't be equal, authorized_keys would be bigger, and that wouldn't necessarily mean a mistake was made. So that's why you need to elaborate on what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check `/var/log/auth.log` as stated in the comment. Almost always you will find your answer there.

I have these permissions set for my servers and locally:

#### Server

```
drwx------ remoteuser group ~/.ssh
-rw------- remoteuser group ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#### Locally

```
drwx------ user group ~/.ssh
-rw------- user group ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw----r-- user group ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your `authorized_keys` file others readable?  Isn't the `authorized_keys` file supposed to be 600?

Comment: Good catch. This is a really old response, and I should probably edit it.